# Macro Paradise 2.11 versus 2.10

Tags: scala, macros

The [Scala Macro Paradise](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html) is available for 2.11 and 2.10. For 2.10, it says

> you can already make use of quasiquotes in production versions of 2.10.x

Does that mean that 2.10 paradise is a subset of the 2.11 version? For instance, can I experiment with type macros, using Scala 2.10, or is that a feature for which I need to work with 2.11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro paradise have been recently revamped into a [compiler plugin](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html). It includes much improved support of quasiquotes (source compatible with 2.11) and macro annotations. Type macros and untyped macros have been discontinued (in favor of macro annotations.)

Answer (score 2):

Paradise 2.10.x only includes quasiquotes because of binary compatibility restrictions. Thanks for the excellent question btw. I've updated the guide [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html).

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you only get access to quasiquotations. You compile your macro with this special 2.10 version of macro paradise, and can then use them in code that compiles against (normal, non macro paradise) scala 2.10. This is possible because quasiquotations are used when compiling macros themselves, and expand to normal macro code that uses nothing else that APIs available in Scala 2.10 already (creating trees explicitly, node by node). So you can the use those macros in Scala 2.10 code, the compiler won't see the difference.

On the other hand type macros cannot use this trick, because they are not available at all in scala 2.10. Generating types at compile time is not something that the scala 2.10 compiler knows how to do, so you will definitely need to compile your client code (your actual code, as opposed as just the macro code) using a 2.11 compiler.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I'll be playing then with 2.11, even if I'll have to wait for its release to be using it across published libs.